# Can someone explain angular momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

How is it possible that $\omega{}r$ is constant, and $\omega{}r^2$ is constant too?

i understood that when an object rotates on a circle, the momentum needs to be conserved so $v$ is a constant... ?

$\omega=\frac{v}{r}$ so when $r$ decrease then $\omega$ increases.

From conservation of the angular momentum it seems like $v=\omega{}r$ will change... can you explain me where is my error?

Comment: Motion on "a circle of shrinking size" is another way to say you're *not* moving on a circle. So $v$ doesn't need to be constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A net force changes linear momentum and a net torque changes angular momentum.  For a body in circular motion at constant speed $v$ the velocity $\vec v$, a vector, is not constant since the velocity is continuously changing direction.  The linear momentum $\vec p = m \vec v$, a vector, is not constant and therefore there must be net force acting.  For a body twirled with a string the force is provided by the string, and for uniform circular motion the force is a centripetal force and is $\vec F = {m v^2 \over r} \hat n$ where $r$ is the radius and $\hat n$ is a unit vector in the radially inward direction.  If the string force is increased and a smaller circle of "orbit" is established, $v^2/r$ is increased.  Using $v = \omega r$, $\omega^2r$ is increased and is not constant.  For the circular motion case, the angular momentum in the stable orbit is $\vec L = rmv \enspace \hat k  = m \omega r^2 \enspace \hat k$ where $\hat k$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane of the orbit.  There is no net torque since the centripetal force vector is 90 degrees from the velocity vector, so the angular momentum is constant, and $r^2 \omega$ is constant.  For an initial circular orbit at $v_1, r_1$ and a final circular orbit at $v_2, r_2$, due to constant angular momentum $r_1^2 \omega_1 = r_2^2 \omega_2$, or $r_1 v_1 = r_2 v_2$; $v_1 \ne v_2$ and $\omega_1 \ne \omega_2$. See a basic physics textbook discussion of motion under a central force for more details, such as one of the books by Halliday and Resnick.

- Update per your comment.

$\vec p = m \vec v$, $m$ is constant so ${d \vec p \over dt} = m {d \vec v \over dt} = ma$. For uniform circular motion $\vec F = {mv^2 \over r} \hat n$.$\vec F = m \vec a = {mv^2 \over r} \hat n$ so $\vec a = {v^2 \over r} \hat n$.  $\vec a$ is not constant due to the net centripetal force.  The net torque $\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F$ has magnitude $\tau = rF sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec F$.  For uniform circular motion $\theta$ is 90 degrees so $\tau = 0$.  Since $\vec \tau = {d \vec L \over dt}$ where $\vec L$ is angular momentum, for uniform circular motion $\vec L$ is constant.  Bottom line: for uniform circular motion the linear momentum $\vec p$ is not constant due to the external centripetal force, but the angular momentum $\vec L$ is constant since there is no external torque (because the force vector and the distance vector are at 90 degrees).

Here are some basic equations for angular momentum $\vec L$ and torque $\vec \tau$ for a simple point mass. $\vec L = \vec r \times m \vec v$, $\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F = \vec r \times m\vec a= {d \vec L \over dt}$. You need to understand vectors, cross products and time derivatives thereof.  These relationships are discussed in detail in any of the Halliday and Resnick basic physics textbooks.

Comment: hellow thank you for your answear! it seems to be correct mathematically, but i still cannot understand what that angular momentum is. and why there is an angular acceleration if no external force acts, so i went back to $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and from that to $a=-\frac{dm}{dt}\cdot{}\frac{v}{m}$ can you explain that equation to me sorry for stupid quuestion

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: so i'v read your answear, and i think i realised what my error was: if $r$ decreases then a body is moving on a spiral and not-perpendicular force causes speed increase. but $L(=rmv)$ is just constant parameter that is somehow hidden and we dont need to care about that.

Comment: but whats happening with the Inertia $I$ ??? where is it going to, can it disappear contrary to mass?

Comment: this may be summarised ad:
$\tau{}=I\alpha$ only works when $I$ is constant

Comment: Yes τ=Iα  assumes a rigid body rotating about a fixed axis in which case I is constant. For the circular motion of a particle, it the radius changes I changes.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity will not be constant if the radius is changed. For a particle of mass m, the angular momentum is $mr^2\omega$, which must be constant. It can also be written $rmv$ So if r is decreased, then $v$ increases. So $mv$ is not conserved, but it is not linear momentum since $v$ in this case is velocity that is constantly changing in direction.

Perhaps you haven't done moments of inertia yet, but the moment of inertia of a body is the sum of the moment of inertia of every particle of mass ${\delta}m$ i.e. $\sum{r^2{\delta}m} = I$, and the angular momentum is then $I\omega$. The classic example often given for conservation of angular momentum is a skater doing a pirouette. She starts off spinning slowly with her arms (and possibly one leg) out and then, by bringing them close to her body, she reduces her moment of inertia and thereby increases her angular velocity (spin speed).

Comment: "So if r is decreased, then ω increases. v=rω so of course that does change - it increaes with ω." – but does'nt that contradict the conservation  of momentum?

Comment: In the absence of an external torque, as r decreases ω increases. The product remains unchanged.

Comment: @R.W.Bird hellow, but CoAM principle implies that $\omega{}r^2$ is constant ?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of the wrong product. It is the ω$r^2$ that remains unchanged.

Comment: hellow your answear seems to be correct mathematically, but i still cannot understand what that angular momentum is. and why there is an angular acceleration if no external force acts, so i went back to $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and from that to $a=-\frac{dm}{dt}\cdot{}\frac{v}{m}$ can you explain that equation to me sorry for stupid quuestion